# A linear form $f$ is continuous respect to weak$^{\star}$ topology if and only if there exists $x \in E$ such that $f(x')=x'(x)$ for all $x'\in E'$.

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, weak-convergence, weak-topology

Let $E$ normed vector space. Show that a linear form $f:(E',\sigma(E',E))\rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ is continuous if and only if there exists $x \in E$ such that $f(x')=x'(x)$ for all $x'\in E'$.

**Remark:** Here $E'$ is the dual space of $E$, and $\sigma(E',E)$ is the weak$^{\star}$ topology.

**The problem:** The direction $\Leftarrow)$ is immediate of the definition of $\sigma(E',E)$, my problem is the direction $\Rightarrow)$, note that this dirrection can be reduced to show that if $f$ is continuous with respect to the topology $\sigma(E',E)$, then $f\in J(E)$  where $J$ is the canonical application
$$\begin{array}{rclrcl}
J:E &\longrightarrow & E'' \\
x &\longmapsto& J(x):&E' &\rightarrow & \mathbb{K}\\
&&&x' &\mapsto & x'(x).
 \end{array}$$

Note that if $E$ is reflexive then the result is trivial, but $E$ is any normed vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f:(E',\sigma(E',E))\to \mathbb{K}$ is continuous, then there exists some $x_1,\cdots, x_m\in E$ such that $\lvert f(x')\rvert \leq \sum_{i=1}^m \lvert x_i(x')\rvert\forall x'\in X'$. Hence $\ker f\subset \cap_{i=1}^m\ker x_i$, thus there exists some scalars $\alpha_1,\cdots, \alpha_m$ such that $ f=\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i x_i\in X$.

Comment: Here is more genneral result. https://cding.xyz/the-space-of-continuous-functionals-on-dual-space-is-the-predual-space/